# Does higher education increase international competitiveness?

Tags: united-kingdom, university

In [this story](http://www.timeshighereducation.co.uk/news/undergraduate-numbers-cap-to-be-abolished-osborne/2009667.article), the UK chancellor is quoted as saying:

> Each year, around 60,000 young people who have worked hard at school,
>   got the results, want to go on learning and want to take out a loan to
>   pay for it, are prevented from doing so because of an arbitrary cap.
>
> That makes no sense when we have a far lower proportion of people
>   going to university than even the United States, let alone countries
>   like South Korea.
>
> **Access to higher education is a basic tenet of economic success in the
>   global race.**

Is there evidence for this?

Comment: I can't decide whether he means "Giving citizens access to higher education leads to greater economic success of the country" or "Receiving higher education gives greater economic success to the student." If the latter, there is a related question [here](http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/9693/do-high-school-leaving-exams-decide-your-future)

Comment: @Oddthinking: I think it's the former. I've added some more context.

Comment: Thanks. In that case, it is going to be very difficult to resolve the confounding factors. Do you have a feel for what a good answer might look like?

Comment: Maybe a study showing that higher education is cost-effective on a macroeconomic scale, and can thus increase exports?